# Lazy loading implementation in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning about TensorFlow from [Lecture note 2: TensorFlow Ops](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/2017/lectures/notes_02.pdf). Everything was fine until I met "The trap of lazy loading" at the end of the Note. I tried to re-write the script that demonstrates "lazy loading" as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(10, name='x')
y = tf.Variable(20, name='y')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in range(10):
        sess.run(tf.add(x, y))
    print (sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()))
```

and result:

```
...
node {
  name: "Add_8"
  op: "Add"
  input: "x/read"
  input: "y/read"
  attr {
    key: "T"
    value {
      type: DT_INT32
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "Add_9"
  op: "Add"
  input: "x/read"
  input: "y/read"
  attr {
    key: "T"
    value {
      type: DT_INT32
    }
  }
```

The Note explained that:
"***There are two ways to avoid this bug. First, always separate the definition of ops and their execution when you can. But when it is not possible because you want to group related ops into classes, you can use Python property to ensure that your function is only loaded once when it’s first called.***"
I want to apply Python property for the script above to avoid the trap of lazy loading. 
Please help me.

Comment: You can refer [Structuring Your TensorFlow Models](https://danijar.com/structuring-your-tensorflow-models/).

Comment: Yep, i referred to this page but it was very difficult to understand for me.

Comment: It's confused what you want. You want to do this 'lazy loading' getting results immediately when you put nodes in your graph? 
It smells like you want a `tf.executing_eagerly()` in TF 1.X. `tf.add(x,y)` only puts node without data. There's no value in x and y until you do `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`. The mechanism of TF tell us that one should put empty node first then initialize finally run.

Comment: Thank Zézouille, but i don't care about the graph. My script was used to demonstrate about "lazy loading" and i used the graph as an evidence about unexpected result of the lazy loading implementation. I just want to apply Python property for my script to avoid "lazy loading"  which is based on advice from the Note (bold text from my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method assumes that you want to group related ops into classes. So your code is equivalent to the following：

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = tf.Variable(10, name='x')
        self.y = tf.Variable(20, name='y')

    @property
    def add(self):
        self._value = tf.add(self.x,self.y)
        return self._value

with tf.Session() as sess:
    test = Test()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in range(10):
        sess.run(test.add)
    print(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())
    # writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("tensorboard_model",tf.get_default_graph())
    # writer.close()

# print
...
node {
  name: "Add_9"
  op: "Add"
  input: "x/read"
  input: "y/read"
  attr {
    key: "T"
    value {
      type: DT_INT32
    }
  }
}
...
```

You can use `tensorboard` to see your operation nodes as follow:
[image]

But we can use use a [custom decorators](https://blog.apcelent.com/python-decorator-tutorial-with-example.html) that behaves like `@property` to ensure that your function is only loaded once when it’s first called. The following code is from [Structuring Your TensorFlow Models](https://danijar.com/structuring-your-tensorflow-models/).

```
import functools
def lazy_property(function):
    attribute = '_cache_' + function.__name__
    @property
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def decorator(self):
        if not hasattr(self, attribute):
            setattr(self, attribute, function(self))
        return getattr(self, attribute)
    return decorator
```

And we can use it:

```
@lazy_property
def add(self):
    self._value = tf.add(self.x,self.y)
    return self._value
```

Running again yields the following results.
[image]

Comment: Thank giser_yugang very much. Great answer.